# Android Socket.IO with Fragments

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

I have my application that is using Koush's web-sockets/Socket.IO library for just one fragment. (https://github.com/koush/android-websockets)

I am having some problems getting the Socket.IO client to work correctly with the fragment lifecycle and its threads.

For the most part, my fragment looks like this:

```
public class ScoresFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    public SocketIOClient socket;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        createSocket();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        try {
            this.socket.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        socket.connect();
        super.onResume();
    }

    public void createSocket() {
        this.socket = new SocketIOClient(URI.create("http://blah-url"), new SocketIOClient.Handler() {
            //Required methods here
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Everything for the layout here
    }
}
```

And the error I'm getting is in the onPause() method when I try to disconnect the socket.
The socket connects just fine, but as soon as I change fragments I get a crash.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.codebutler.android_websockets.SocketIOClient.cleanup(SocketIOClient.java:195)
    at com.codebutler.android_websockets.SocketIOClient.disconnect(SocketIOClient.java:188)
    at edu.bgsu.asf.athletics.fragments.ScoresFragment.onPause(ScoresFragment.java:14)
```

I read somewhere that I may have to be wary of threads and I may have to use a handler for this, but the git page for web-sockets doesn't allude to having to use anything like that. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

The sections of SocketIOClient.java:

```
public void disconnect() throws IOException {
    cleanup(); //Line 188
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////

private void cleanup() {
    mClient.disconnect();
    mClient = null;

    mSendLooper.quit(); //Line 195
    mSendLooper = null;
    mSendHandler = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create static socket and connect it in parent activity in which your fragment lies. After that when your fragment created subscribe via emit method. And close socket in onStop method of parent activity. Follow these instructions to make it work.